# Download code from GCloud VM instance with expired RStudio Server license

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, rstudio-server

I had created a Google compute engine (virtual machine) instance with RStudio Server being unaware that RStudio Server is a licensed software. Now, my trial license for RStudio has expired, and I cannot login to my R sessions anymore.

However, I had written some code which I need to recover. How do I download the files?

I have SSH-ed into my virtual machine but cannot find the relevant files or a way to download them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I was able to recover the files by performing the following steps:

- SSH to the virtual machine
- Once you are in the virtual machine run the following command: `cd ../rstudio-user/`
- Now  `ls` there you will see the file structure you used to see in the RStudio Server interface}
- Navigate using `cd` and `ls` between the folders to get to the desired file
- Once you are in the desired location (where with an `ls` you can see the files you want to recover) run the following command: `pwd`
- Click on the Engine and go to download file
- Enter the full path of the file you want to download, it will be something like: `/home/rstudio-user/FILENAME.R`
- Click on Download

You can do this for each of the files you want to recover.

In case you want to recover a full folder its easier to compress to a zip file and then to download it.

Comment: try `cd ..` and then `ls` this will list the directories over there and once you have that list iwith `cd` go to the directory that have a name that tells you that is the rstudio server username